# How to specify a dependencies that has profiles

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-profiles

I'd like add one dependency, but there's different profiles in in this dependency pom file, how can I specify the profile when I add this dependency ? Thanks

Comment: simple answer to this. It's not possible cause profiles are only for build time not for the comsuming time point...And why do you need a profile to use a dependency?